# ember assets - "public" assets should not be fingerprinted but they are?

Tags: ember.js, build

In my Ember.js 3.8 project I have an image file in :

`/public/assets/images/foo.png`

... According to [this (admittedly a little out of date)](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation) files put in `public/assets/images` should be available unchanged when referenced as `assets/images`.

[This](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/asset-compilation/) is up to date, a little less explicit but says that items placed beneath `public` will end up beneath `assets`.

When I do a production build the file I have in `/public/assets/images/` ends up `/dist/assets/images/` but with a finger print, eg `foo-97cf8c0765aefa517d22e1fc71f43d6e.png`.

Am I meant to explicitly suppress the finger-printing ? The doco seems to suggest that's not necessary ?

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at these [ember-cli docs](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation), specifically:

> When the environment is production (e.g. ember build
>   --environment=production), the addon will automatically fingerprint your js, css, png, jpg, and gif assets by appending an md5 checksum to
>   the end of their filename (e.g.
>   assets/yourapp-9c2cbd818d09a4a742406c6cb8219b3b.js). In addition, your
>   html, js, and css files will be re-written to include the new name.
>   There are a few options you can pass in to EmberApp in your
>   ember-cli-build.js to customize this behavior.

From a fingerprinting perspective, it makes sense to fingerprint even your images, since you may need to change them and do not want to have to wait until cache TTLs expire.

You can remove specific files as such

```
fingerprint: {
  exclude: ['assets/images/user.png']
}
```

or whole file extensions

```
fingerprint:{
  extensions: ['js', 'css', /* all the extensions you do want excluding image ones */]
}
```

Comment: With `exclude`, you can exclude also directory (not only specific files). E.g. `exclude: ['assets/images']` to exclude all files which are in `assets/images` (or more specific - where file path contains `assets/images`)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `fingerprint` in your `ember-cli-build.js`, `fingerprinting` is `enabled` by default if current environment is `production`.

```
// ember-cli-build.js

const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp({
    fingerprint: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });

  //...
  return app.toTree();
};
```

More information you can find by this [link](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/asset-compilation/#fingerprintingandcdnurls)